# Zend Framework Page not found

Tags: php, zend-framework

Help me, please. I go to message module and Zend Framework output:
http://screencast.com/t/QuUPpTFC

What should I do?

Comment: you should post your code please

Answer (score 1):

This seems the default ErrorController error action output and it seems you have a problem somewhere into the dispatch process.

If you are stuck at this point the best thing you can do is try to understand the dispatch process by reading the manual pages:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.front.html

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.basics.html

http://nethands.de/download/zenddispatch_en.pdf

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html

Answer (score 0):

Does that module, controller or action exist? That 404 error is generated when Zend Framework can't find one of these.